# How to download a file using wget when url has parameters?

Tags: download, wget, url

The URL is this:

https://software-download.microsoft.com/db/Win10_21H1_English_x64.iso?t=52dbec9b-63f5-47e9-b4b2-ccbcbb6beb7a&e=1627124449&h=42e9a2a8e1f843e5a4573960dc07feaa

The error is:

wget https://software-download.microsoft.com/db/Win10_21H1_English_x64.iso?t=5e79c7f7-ad0d-4431-ad01-7139b298f3bc&e=1627210844&h=94f2c2f458187bd78dc6eca220b4d504

```
--2021-07-24 00:07:57--  https://software-download.microsoft.com/db/Win10_21H1_English_x64.iso?t=52dbec9b-63f5-47e9-b4b2-ccbcbb6beb7a
Resolving software-download.microsoft.com (software-download.microsoft.com)... 117.18.232.200
Connecting to software-download.microsoft.com (software-download.microsoft.com)|117.18.232.200|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2021-07-24 00:07:59 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

'e' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'h' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be useful for you to include your `wget` command in the post.
Here are some comments:

- The ampersand character (`&`) is a special character.
  You should either enclose the URL in apostrophes or double-quotes
  to avoid the shell getting it (`wget "https..."`), or you should escape all special characters (`\&`).
- As you're getting HTTPS, to avoid checking the validity of the certificate,
  add the parameter `--no-check-certificate` to the command.

Comment: I wasn't using the quotes. Thanks alot.

Comment: It didn't work to this case: `wsl wget --no-check-certificate -O localidades.csv "https://opendata.arcgis.com/api/v3/datasets/899168c8feab4230a9f795ed07cdde7b_0/downloads/data?format=csv&spatialRefId=31983&where=1%3D1"`